# What is a really simple explanation of unit testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pylons

I've never done any unit testing before, and would like to learn what it is and how it can be useful in my Python code.

I've read through a few Python unit testing tutorials online but they're all so complicated and assume an extended programming background.  I'm using Python with Pylons to create a simple web app.

Any simple examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: "unit testing tutorials online but they're all so complicated"  All?  Can you provide specific links to tutorials which are too complicated?

Answer (score 5):

Consider this.

Here's a class we've written.

```
class Something( object ):
    def __init__( self, a, b ):
        self.a= a
        self.b= b
    def sum( self ):
        return self.a+self.b+self.a
```

That's a test for that class.

```
import unittest
class TestSomething( unittest.TestCase ):
    def setUp( self ):
        self.s = Something( 1, 2 )
    def test_should_sum( self ):
        self.assertEquals( 3, self.s.sum() )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Does the class -- as a stand-alone unit -- pass the test?

If not, what's the bug?

We've taken the class -- as a stand-alone unit -- and tested it.  That's unit testing.

Comment: Thank you!  How do you typically run TestSomething?  From the python console?  Is there a better way?  Also, what does "if __name__ == "__main__":" do?  Thanks.

Comment: @ensnare: Yes.  And if you don't know what `__main__` is about, search stack overflow.  Do not ask that question -- it's been answered here, heavily.